# Class 'CWebModule' not found when adding Yii2 Quiz

Tags: php, yii2

I have added yii2 quiz module in my project

I have added the module inside the frontend/modules/quiz

Then in the app's main.php i have added something like

```
'modules' => [
            'quiz' => [
              'class' => 'app\modules\quiz\Module',
            ]
],
```

Then after running it, I'm getting the "CWebModule not found".

```
class Module extends CWebModule{
......
}
```

My module class extending CWebModule.
How to fix this error?

Comment: Did you added path for `CWebModule` class in  `Module`. For example `vwndor/extension/models/CWebModule`.

Comment: CWebModule sounds like something for Yii 1. Are you sure it's for Yii 2?

Comment: did you declare it with a `use` statement before the class?

Comment: Looks like you've downloaded Yii 1.x version instead of Yii 2 version.